# can't send authToken in Apolloclient in react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I need to send authToken along with the uri in appolloclient .
I tried doing it this way but it doesn't seem to send the auttoken .

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'some url',
  request: async operation => {
   const token = 'MvHE4SXPDa17yzh6Shswhsvwhswdwvd';
   operation.setContext({
     headers: {
       authorization: token
     }
   });
  }
})
```

I tried this way too

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'some url,
     headers: {
       authorization: token
     }
   });
```

What is the correct procedure to send headers with apollo client ?

Answer (score 0):

check this out

`const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
      // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
      const token = await getToken();

      // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: token,
        },
      };
    });
    const newLink = authLink.concat(resetUser);
    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: newLink.concat(link),
      // link,
      cache: new InMemoryCache({
        addTypename: false,
      }).restore(),
    });`